# building an inner Join from doctrine in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a schema.yml file defined this way:

```
email:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    id: { type: integer, notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true }
    correo: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    nombre: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    apellido: { type: string(255), notnull: true }

lista:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:  
    id: { type: integer, notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true }
    nombre: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    descripcion: { type: string(255), notnull: false }

email_lista:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    email_id: { type: integer }
    lista_id: { type: integer }
  relations:
    email: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: email_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: emailrelation }
    lista: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: lista_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: listarelation }
```

Then, I try to fetch all the records from the *email* model that do not belong to lista with lista_id equals to one.

Here's the method on the emailTable.php class:

```
 public function getEmailsNotBlacklist()
    {
   $q = $this->createQuery('c')        
       ->leftJoin('c.email_lista m')
       ->Where('m.lista_id != ?',1);
       ->orderBy('m.lista_id ASC');       

   return $q->execute();
     }
```

The result is an error:

[image: Error]

What might be causing this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the YML syntax there (don't usually use curly brace style) but I can't see how your relation knows that "email" is the model "email" does it not need to be: `email: { model: email, onDelete: CASCADE, local: email_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: email }`

Comment: The name of the relation has to correspond exactly with that of the model. In this case, the model is email. I think the problem was giving the model an alias of email. That creates confusion.

Comment: If you've solved it pop some notes in an answer, just in case other people have same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that would not come up with an error:

```
       public function getEmailsNotBlacklist()
       {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()        
       ->from('email sr')
       ->innerJoin('sr.emailrelation m' )
       ->Where('m.lista_id <> ?',1);
       //->orderBy('m.lista_id ASC');        

  return $q->execute();
}
```

What I was taking wrong was that the foreignAlias is what is to be referenced in the join, and not the name of the model.

Comment: By the way, I changed the relations name from email and lista, respectively,  to emailrelation and listarelation to avoid confusion.